# display sql syntax in Oracle's sqlplus?

Tags: oracle

What is in Oracle's sqlplus equivalent of Linux's man or --help ?

When I'm in sqlplus and type help index, I get some commands displayed, but there is no way to get specific sql syntax. For example if I type 'help select' I get:

```
SP2-0172 No HELP matching this tiopic was found.
```

Of course, I would like to get all available options for select command.

How can I get info or sql syntax while I'm at sql prompt ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install this feature, log in with `SYSTEM` account and run this SQL script:

```
@%ORACLE_HOME%\SQLPLUS\ADMIN\HELP\HLPBLD.SQL HELPUS.SQL
```

After *`HLPBLD.SQL`* run, you have created the help tables on SQL-Plus.

Answer (score 0):

You actually seem not to need a help for sqlplus itself, but for the SELECT-statement.

There is not a proper way to get help on query syntax inside the sqlplus, instead I recommend Oracle's documentation site [and in this case this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702).

(Older Oracle-versions have their own documentations there too)

In practice the official documentation may be too comprehensive to get things done, so, keep Google as a close friend also.